# Live migration failure: not all arguments were converted to strings

Tags: openstack

Live migration to another compute node fails. I receive an error in the nova-compute log of the host compute node:

```
2020-10-21 15:15:52.496 614454 DEBUG nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] About to invoke the migrate API _live_migration_operation /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py:7808
2020-10-21 15:15:52.497 614454 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] Live Migration failure: not all arguments converted during string formatting
2020-10-21 15:15:52.498 614454 DEBUG nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] Migration operation thread notification thread_finished /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py:8149
2020-10-21 15:15:52.983 614454 DEBUG nova.virt.libvirt.migration [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] VM running on src, migration failed _log /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/migration.py:361
2020-10-21 15:15:52.984 614454 DEBUG nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] Fixed incorrect job type to be 4 _live_migration_monitor /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py:7978
2020-10-21 15:15:52.985 614454 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] [instance: bc41148a-8fdd-4be1-b8fa-468ee17a4f5b] Migration operation has aborted
```

Please help me with a solution to this issue.

Comment: Please use code tags to make your output more readable.

Comment: can you share more detail about the packages & OS and other detail of your set up?

Comment: Hello @auvipy thank you for responding. The operating system I use for the entire open stack deployment is ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I installed Openstack stein packages. kindly let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: did you try the latest ubuntu 20.04 lts with newer libvirt?

Comment: @auvipy we decided to use Openstack stein and there isn't a stein release for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: actually i need to know the deployment model you followed to track down the root of the error